# Getting JS error after upgrade Sitecore version 6.6 to 7.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

We have upgraded Sitecore v6.6 to Sitecore v7.0.But I'm not able to publish.When I clicked on **Publish** link nothing happens.
Then I checked error in Mozilla Web Console as given below:

[image]

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: this.browser.showModalDialog is not a function.
```

What did I miss.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `showModalDialog` is deprecated in modern browsers.

`showModalDialogs` was used in pre-7.1 Sitecore releases.

What you need is to install a proper package for you Sitecore version.

Here is a list of Sitecore Support patches for different Sitecore versions:

[Sitecore Knowledge Base: Sitecore does not work in Chrome 37 and later](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527)

or

[Fixing Chrome's ShowModalDialog JavaScript Error In Sitecore](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/fixing-showmodaldialog-javascript-error-in-chrome-for-sitecore)

Comment: As you said `showModalDialogs` was used in pre-7.1 Sitecore releases and I have upgraded to v7.0 so this should work properly.Isn't it?

Comment: By `pre-7.1` I mean all releases **before 7.1**. So this is used in 7.0 and is now deprecated by the modern browsers.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it.
As per suggestion given in your link Now I'll try to upgrade version to 7.1 so I think this issue will be resolved.

Comment: When we upgrade sitecore existing version through AdminWizard Does this process also make changes in database OR only physical files/dlls only updated?

Comment: I don't know the answer for that question. I suggest you create another question - bigger chance someone will notice it

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, I'd suggest you upgrade all the way up to 7.2 at least, there's not many architectural difference (i.e. MongoDB in 7.5)

Comment: @jammykam: Did you mean that I don't need to test/browse sitecore until I upgrade till V 7.2. and all such type issue will be resolved when I reach v7.2

Comment: No, just that if you are upgrading you might as well upgrade to 7.2 if possible.

Comment: @Marek: I did upgrade to v7.2 and that issue resolved.